# C++ Class with sqlite database

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using Qt creator IDE with pure c++ coding. I need to create a class with 2 member variables A & B (also added in the table) and 3 public and private functions.

Public functions: to check whether database exists ,if exists open and read data A & B else call the 3 functions from private. 2nd function is to generate a 26 char array and store in 25 digit no. Using `srand()` return it - `getA()`. 3rd function is to take sha256 hash concatenating 2nd function + time-stamp - `getB()`.

Private functions: to create an sqlite database,to initialize a basic table structure (char A|char B|blob C).3rd function is to generate details to store to database and also to A & B. Both `getA()` and `getB()` is called from this function to generate details.

CODE:

```
  class Init  {

   char AppID[50];
   char AppCode[50];

 //create sqlite database
 int DbInit() {

    sqlite3 *db;
        if(sqlite3_open("Init.db", &db))
            cout<<"opened database successfully\n";
        else
            cout<< "failed to create database\n";
        return 0;

       }
   //initialize table
   int tableGen() {

    string query = "CREATE TABLE tableInit(AppID TEXT(25), AppCode TEXT(60),Cert BLOB)";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmnt;
    cout<< "creating table statement"<<endl;
    sqlite3_prepare(db, query.c_str() , query.size(), &stmnt, NULL );
    if(sqlite3_step(stmnt)  !=SQLITE_DONE)
        cout<< "didnt create table"<<endl;


  }
  //generate details to store to database and also into member functions.
  int AppGen() {
            both getappid and get appcode is called to generate details.
  }



   public:
  Init() {}


  //check whether database exists if exists read data else call the private functions .
  bool start() {

   int rc = sqlite3_open("Init.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY);
   if(rc = SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_stmt *statement;
       sqlite3_prepare(db,"SELECT AppID,AppCode FROM tableInit",-1,&statement,0);
       sqlite3_step(statement);
   }
   else

       Init::DbInit();
       Init::tablegen();
       Init::AppGen();


  }
   // generate appid 
   int GetAppID() {
          generate a 25 digit number and store it in an array using rand()

  }

  //take sha256 hash concating appid + time-stamp
   int  getcode() {

    }
```

How can I define `appgen()`,`appid()` and `code()` ?

Comment: I have created the class with the member variables and defined the functions.I am stuck with the SQlite database part...

Comment: thanks Vasim for the edit ...

Comment: What are you stuck with?

Comment: Show us some code, a [small example](http://sscce.org/) at best.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this sample will be helpful http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm

Comment: thanks.... how do i generate the public funcions (using srand() &  sha256 hash library) .

Comment: @AMZZ What do you mean by 'generate public functions'?

Comment: sorry... define these functions?

Comment: @AMZZ Sorry, I don't understand where your problem is. You wanted to remove QSql... from your program, didn't you? If yes then I gave you an example how to use pure SQLite API. If you want to remove whole Qt and still want to have GUI, then you need to decide which GUI framework to use (if any). And for the sake why are you asking for srand/sha256?